# Does discarding your commander to the command zone trigger discard effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

*NOTE: This question was asked before the commander rules update that removed the replacement effect. Discarded or killed commanders now go to graveyard first as normal then move to the command zone from the graveyard as a state based action*

---

There is a rule in commander that lets you put your commander in the command zone instead of other zones:

> If a Commander would be put into a library, hand, graveyard or exile from anywhere, its owner may choose to move it to the command zone instead.

There are additional clarifications:

> This is a replacement effect. It applies last and may apply multiple times to an event.
>
> The creature never goes to the original destination zone and will not trigger abilities that trigger based on going there (e.g. "dies" triggers).

So, if I have to discard my hand, and my commander is in it, and I choose to put him in the command zone, does that trigger [Liliana's Caress](http://magiccards.info/query?q=liliana%27s%20caress&v=card&s=cname) or similar cards?

Comment: Why in the world does that have a downvote?

Comment: [Here](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/569907-waste-not-vs-leyline-of-the-void) is a related discussion on another site.

Comment: @Rainbolt That's helpful. Three of us were googling for 5-10 minutes and never ran across that. Now we have a question on SE for posterity.

Comment: Yes, you still take the discard action even if the effect of the discard action is modified

Comment: @ikegami A) Don't answer in comments. B) That's been established, read the answer.

Comment: @DCShannon, I didn't answer in the comments. As you pointed out, I merely rephrased. To be specific, I distilled the answer into its key point, **which had gone unstated**. It was a worthwhile addition.

Comment: @ikegami If you want to improve the answer, comment on the answer. He won't hear you here.

Comment: @DCShannon regarding your answer on this question (I can't comment on it because it's deleted), If you want to keep an incorrect answer, then you have to expect downvotes. We use votes to indicate correctness and quality, and comments are ephemeral, so having just a comment indicating that an answer is incorrect is insufficient reason to *not* vote on an answer's correctness. One common workaround for this is to have the correct answer in the answer, along with the text of the incorrect answer with a statement that it is incorrect *in the answer itself*.

Comment: I am impressed that you were able to identify that your [wrong answer has value.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264293/254466) You did the right thing by leaving it up originally, and its understandable that you took it down after losing so much reputation. People are going to downvote wrong answers no matter what you say. You get to decide whether it is worth it to prevent someone else from making the same mistake.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I was surprised it kept getting downvotes because I spend most of my time on RPG SE, where I would have expected people to understand what was going on, downvote it to -2 or so, and then just leave it. Votes are often tied to correctness, but that's due to correctness's high correlation with usefulness. Votes are for usefulness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does count as being discarded.

Discard is a [Keyword Action](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Keyword_action) that means:

> **701.7a** To discard a card, move it from its owner’s hand to that player’s graveyard.

The Commander replacement effect changes this to be:

> To discard a card, move it from its owner’s hand to that player’s command zone.

Discard is a keyword action that tells you to move a card from one zone to another like destroy, sacrifice, or exile. The action doesn't care if parts of it were replaced with other actions, it still happened. Similarly if you have a [Dragon Appeasement](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragon%20Appeasement) and sacrifice your commander you will get to draw a card.

Also since the actually being put into the graveyard is being replaced discarding your commander and putting it in the command zone will not trigger any "when this card enters the graveyard from anywhere" triggers like [Ulamog, the Infinite Gyre](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ulamog%2C%20the%20Infinite%20Gyre), similar to how a sacrificed commander will not trigger any "dies" triggers.

[Leyline of the Void](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20the%20Void) sets up a similar type of replacement effect, it exiles cards instead of putting them in the graveyard, and it has this ruling:

> If your opponent discards a card while you control Leyline of the Void, abilities that function when that card is discarded (such as Liliana's Caress's ability, or a madness ability of the discarded card) still work, even though that card never reaches that player's graveyard. In addition, spells or abilities that check the characteristics of the discarded card (such as Chandra Ablaze's first ability) can find that card in exile.

Comment: For some reason I can't think of an example off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are tons of rulings on Gatherer about things like this; could be something helpful to include if you can think of one. The general idea of "if part of X is replaced with something else, it is still X" is very familiar.

Comment: @DCShannon 'Dies' is different because it triggers off of being put in the graveyard, discard is an action to put something in the graveyard but doesn't actually care if the thing gets there.

Comment: @DCShannon I think you've misunderstood subtly. Nothing ever instructs you to make something "die". Instead, a card might say "destroy target creature", which normally means put it in your graveyard, but something could cause it to be exiled. The replacement effect replaces part of that effect; the creature was still destroyed, and it just ended up somewhere besides where it usually would. "Die" on the other hand is looking at what actually happens - does something go to the graveyard? The replacement effect has no bearing on that definition.

Comment: "Dies" is a description of an event. If the event does not happen as described in rule 700.4, then it does not count as dying. "Discard" is a keyword action. Even if the results of the action change, the action was still taken.

Comment: @DCShannon This might also help you: if a replacement effect said "if you would discard your commander, move it from your hand to the command zone instead" then that would entirely replace the discard and it'd never happen. But the special commander rules don't replace the whole discard, just where it goes.

Comment: There *is* an analogous ruling on Leyline of the Void that cards that "abilities that function when that card is discarded still work", and it specifically mentions Liliana's Caress as one such card.

Comment: There, the Leyline ruling did it. I also read the [Keyword Action](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Keyword_action) article on MTG Salvation, which helps to clear things up. Might want to make that a link and capitalize it to make it clear that it is an actual thing from the rules.

Comment: @DCShannon I agree that the ruling is more convincing - that's why I mentioned suggested looking for one in the first place. But to be fair, we've been explaining the basis, though. A replacement effect replaces only what it says it replaces. If it doesn't replace the entire discard event, there is still a (modified) discard event. And cards don't say "whenever an unmodified discard event occurs", they just say "whenever you discard a card".

Comment: In addition, rule 701.7c strongly implies that if a card is discarded and an effect moves it to another zone instead of the graveyard, it still counts as a discard. Specifically, it talks about moving the card to a hidden zone instead and then says "If a card is discarded *this way*"